# Testing Receiver Methods in Golang

Tags: unit-testing, go

I'm trying to test and implement an exercise on receiver method from [here](https://exercism.org/tracks/go/exercises/elons-toys).

This basically states the following:

- Cars start with full (100%) batteries
- Each time you drive a car, it covers the it's speed in meters and decreases the remaining battery percentage by its battery drain.
- If a car's battery is below its battery drain percentage, you can't drive the car.

Based on the code snippets, a call `car := NewCar(speed, batteryDrain)` is made before *`car.SomeFunction`*. The test cases [here](https://github.com/exercism/go/blob/main/exercises/concept/elons-toys/elons_toys_test.go) don't actually use it.

I came up with my own test:

```
package nfs2

import "testing"

func TestNewCar(t *testing.T) {
    testcases := []struct{
        description string
        initial Car
        expected Car
    }{
        {
            description: "can drive car",
            initial: Car{
                speed: 5,
                batteryDrain: 2,
                battery: 100,
                distance: 0,
            },
            expected : Car{
                speed: 5,
                batteryDrain: 2,
                battery: 98,
                distance: 5,
            },
        },
        {
            description: "cannot drive car because of battery drain",
            initial: Car{
                speed: 14,
                batteryDrain: 102,
                battery: 100,
                distance: 0,
            },
            expected: Car{
                speed: 14,
                batteryDrain: 102,
                battery: 100,
                distance: 0,
            },
        },
    }

    for _, tc := range testcases {
        t.Run(tc.description, func(t *testing.T) {
            init := tc.initial

            got := init.drive()
            want := tc.expected

            if got != want {
                t.Errorf("Incorrect values:\ngot  %v \nwant %v\n", got, want)
            }
        })
    }
}

func TestDisplayDistance(t *testing.T) {
    testcases := []struct{
        description string
        initial Car
        expected string
    }{
        {
            description: "some distance driven",
            initial: Car{
                speed: 45,
                batteryDrain: 20,
                battery: 100,
                distance: 45,
            },
            expected: "Driven 45 meters",
        },
        {
            description: "no distance driven because of battery drain",
            initial: Car{
                speed: 60,
                batteryDrain: 201,
                battery: 100,
                distance: 0,
            },
            expected: "Driven 0 meters",
        },
    }

    for _, tc := range testcases {
        t.Run(tc.description, func(t *testing.T) {
            initCar := tc.initial

            got := initCar.displayDistance()
            want := tc.expected

            if got != want {
                t.Errorf("Incorrect value of distance driven: got %v, want %v", got, want)
            }
        })
    }

}


func TestDisplayBattery(t *testing.T) {
    testcases := []struct{
        description string
        initial Car
        expected string
    }{
        {
            description: "battery drained completely; car driven to its maximum capacity",
            initial: Car{
                speed: 70,
                batteryDrain: 100,
                battery: 100,
                distance: 0,
            },
            expected: "Battery at 0%",
        },
        {
            description: "no battery drained; car wasn't driven",
            initial: Car{
                speed: 80,
                batteryDrain: 101,
                battery: 100,
                distance: 0,
            },
            expected: "Battery at 100%",
        },
    }


    for _, tc := range testcases {
        t.Run("", func(t *testing.T) {

            initCar := tc.initial
            initCar.drive()

            got := initCar.displayBattery()
            want := tc.expected

            if got != want {
                t.Errorf("Incorrect battery: got %v, want %v", got, want)
            }
        })
    }


}

func TestCanDrive(t *testing.T) {
    testcases := []struct{
        description string
        initial Car
        trackDistance int
        expected bool
    }{
        {
            description: "car can be driven, and can finish track",
            initial: Car{
                speed: 50,
                batteryDrain: 60,
                battery: 100,
                distance: 0,
            },
            trackDistance: 50,
            expected: true,
        },
        {
            description: "car can be driven, but cannot finish track",
            initial: Car{
                speed: 60,
                batteryDrain: 100,
                battery: 100,
                distance: 10,
            },
            trackDistance: 100,
            expected: false,
        },
        {
            description: "car cannot be driven because of battery drain",
            initial: Car{
                speed: 70,
                batteryDrain: 103,
                battery: 100,
                distance: 110,
            },
            trackDistance: 100,
            expected: false,
        },
    }

    for _, tc := range testcases {
        t.Run(tc.description, func(t *testing.T) {
            initCar := tc.initial

            got := initCar.canFinish(tc.trackDistance)
            want := tc.expected

            if got != want {
                t.Errorf("Incorrect value of can finish track: got %v, want %v", got, want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

and implementation:

```
package nfs2

import "fmt"

type Car struct {
    speed int
    batteryDrain int
    battery int
    distance int
}

func (car *Car) drive() Car {
    if car.battery - car.batteryDrain < 0 {
        car = car
    } else {
        car.speed = car.speed
        car.batteryDrain = car.batteryDrain
        car.battery = car.battery - car.batteryDrain
        car.distance = car.distance + car.speed
    }
    return *car
}

func (car *Car) displayDistance() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Driven %v meters", car.distance)
}

func (car *Car) displayBattery() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Battery at %v", car.battery) + "%"
}

/*
Check the number of times the car can be driven.
Compute the maximum distance the car can cover (based on drives remaining)
Compare the maximum distance with the track distance
*/
func (car *Car) canFinish(trackDistance int) bool {
    drivesRemaining := car.battery / car.batteryDrain
    maxDistance := car.speed * drivesRemaining

    return maxDistance >= trackDistance
}
```

All the tests pass, but I'm not fully confident if this is the right approach.

I would also like more clarity on:

- The *drive* method test and implementation
- If there's a way to incorporate the *drive* method in *canFinish* method (this could be beyond the problem spec as task 4 is ambiguous)